# How do I create a doPost(e) function in Apps Script project to capture HTTP POST data from web service?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script to capture data via HTTP POST from Ejunkie. When someone makes a purchase on ejunkie, they can transmit all the order data via HTTP POST to a common notification url (documentation). I want to capture that data so I can get it into a Google Sheet.

So I've setup a sheet with a doPost(e) function like so:

```
// attempt 1
function doPost(e) {
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
  Logger.log(e.parameters);
}

// attempt 2
function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.stringify(e);
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

which I've published as a Web App with access to anyone, and then entered this script URL as the common notification URL in ejunkie.

I've tried a couple of test transactions, but I'm getting nothing in the Logs.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.﻿

Here's the [ejunkie documentation](http://www.e-junkie.com/ej/help.integration.htm) on this subject.

Comment: You have the letter "s" on the end: "parameters."  You can't have that.  It's `e.parameter`  Show the URL that you are using, minus the file ID, does it match the published URL of the Web App?

Comment: Hi @SandyGood thanks for replying and pointing that out. I've changed it to just "parameter" now but not seeing anything. The URL of the published web app (set to access by anyone) is: **https://script.google.com/macros/s/{SCRIPT_ID}/exec** and that's what I've put into ejunkie as the common notification url.

Comment: Markdown got messed up there, that url should read: **`https://script.google.com/macros/s/{SCRIPT_ID}/exec`**

Comment: I don't know what the answer is, and I'm not sure how to proceed from here.  Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in anyway. Cheers!

Comment: I did a quick test, I cannot see anything in the logs as well. However, still able paste stringyfied post data to a spreadsheet, when I made a dummy post using UrlFetchApp. Did you try pasting the data onto a spreadsheet rather than just trying to log it? Did you try making a dummy call? Also is the access set to "anyone even anonymous"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting @JagannathanAlagurajan - can you share your code? I've not been able to paste the data into a Sheet either. I'm trying dummy calls using the Hurl.it service. Yes, access is set to anyone even anonymous.

Comment: I have posted by code below, try it and let me know what happens. Note hurl would also get an echo of the parameter sent, that way you are sure your call went through! All the best!

Comment: Deployed versions (`https://script.google.com/macros/s/<id>/exec`) do not output anything to Logger, instead use the development version (`https://script.google.com/macros/s/<id>/dev?access_token=<your_token>`) as described here: https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#how-to-use-dev-mode-from-outside

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the code I used to post the data to my sheet:

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log("I was called")
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID here")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e))
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

Used curl to make a post request and got echo of the data sent!

Comment: Thanks @jagannathan! I've got it working now. I think I was getting confused by the echo (showing as a 302 redirect?) but now the data is showing in my sheet. I've got the ejunkie data showing up in my sheet now when I test some transactions. Awesome! As @noogui mentioned below, I don't think the Logger.log will do anything, certainly nothing showed up for me int he logs. Again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: The reason you are getting a 302 redirect error: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects. Set your hurl to allow redirect, you will notice your data you sent via post is returned to hurl (i.e echoed back from the server, if you use the above code as is). Hope that make sense! Cheers!

Comment: Ah, ok! Thanks for clarifying @jackbrown, v helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Update 13 April: returning the ContentService will cause a redirect, so simply leaving the return empty avoids this issue and results in a 200 response. Thanks to GDE Riël Notermans in helping me figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using Logger.log() as a way to notify yourself if your calls made it through, try [sending an email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage) to yourself instead. This is the snippet:

```
function doPost(e) {
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')

  MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "youremail@gmail.com",
     subject: "Call Sucessful",
     htmlBody: "I am your <br>" +
               "DATA"
    });
}
```

Just allow the necessary permission if asked. If I'm not mistaken Logger.log is for script editor only and not for your production web apps.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @noogui, your point about the Logger.log not showing the data appears spot on. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Could try something like this? Also you might look @ this thread: [doPost(e) does not return parameters but doGet(e) does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591488/doposte-does-not-return-parameters-but-dogete-does)

```js
function doPost(e) {
  
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined')
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @OblongMedulla. That link was really helpful too. I've got the data showing in my Sheet now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Deployed versions `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<id>/exec`
do not output to Logger.

Instead use the development version `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<id>/dev?access_token=<your_token>` as described here:

https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#how-to-use-dev-mode-from-outside
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57915963/3525368

Access token are vaild for 1 hour only