# Google integration with 3rd Party Apps

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am in the process of creating an app that will log certain amounts of data for teachers. While the data will be kept somehow within the app, is there a way to integrate the use of google forms or sheets with the data?

For example, if I use my app to record data (say that a student was coming to class tardy), is there a way to have that data go to a google sheet/form and always see live data as it's being used through my app?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: You can try using [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL) as it "Converts a relative path within an app/extension install directory to a fully-qualified URL."

Answer (score 0):

You can build a form in your app that posts data to a [standalone google-app script.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43150665/5086349) The app-script can then append the data to any google sheet you specify. I'd also like to recommend Google data studio for displaying real-time data, as it will save a lot of time on not coding the data display ui.