# How to create a method to deploy with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

### I want to create a method to deploy without changing the URL.

#### Assumption

How to deploy manually without changing URLs

- The procedure is as follows

1. Click the Deploy button
2. Click the Manage Deploy button.
3. Click the Edit button
4. Select the new version from "Version" and deploy.

I think the procedure is like this.

I would like to script this procedure, but I could not do it.
How can I do this?

#### Purpose

After entering a value in the spreadsheet and pressing a button
I would like to run the above method and have it deployed.

#### What I have tried

I looked for a method to access the Gas project, but could not find one.

Comment: [tag:google-apps-script-api]

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reflect the latest script to your Web Apps using a Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following patterns?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the following flow is run using Google Apps Script API.

1. Create a new version of the Google Apps Script project using "Method: projects.versions.create".
2. Update the deployment ID with the created version using "Method: projects.deployments.update".

When this flow is reflected in the script, it becomes as follows.

#### 1. Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project.

In this case, it is required to link Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project. For this, you can see the detailed flow at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) or [this repository (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE).

When you see this report, you can see the sample for using Google Apps Script API at "Testing" section.

#### 2. Prepare sample script.

When the above flow is converted to the sample script, it becomes as follows. Please set your script ID and deployment ID.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const scriptId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the Google Apps Script project of your Web Apps.
  const deploymentId = "###"; // This is `###` of your Web Apps URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`;

  const headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };

  // Create version.
  const url1 = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${scriptId}/versions`;
  const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, { method: "post", headers });
  const obj1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());

  // Update deployment.
  const url2 = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${scriptId}/deployments/${deploymentId}`;
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, { method: "put", headers, contentType: "application/json", payload: JSON.stringify({ deploymentConfig: { versionNumber: obj1.versionNumber } }) });

  console.log(res2.getContentText()); // If you want to confirm the response value, please use this line.
}
```

And, please set the following scopes.

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments`

When this script is run, you can use the same Web Apps URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec` without changing `{deploymentId}`. I thought that this might be your expected result.

### Other patterns:

As other patterns, you can see the following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57915963) or [my blog](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/12/07/workaround-reflecting-latest-script-to-deployed-web-apps-created-by-google-apps-script-without-redeploying/).

In this case, I proposed 2 patterns without using Google Apps Script API.

1. Using the developer mode.
2. Using a library.

### References:

- [Google Cloud projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)
- [Method: projects.versions.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/create)
- [Method: projects.deployments.update](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/update)
- [Workaround: Reflecting Latest Script to Deployed Web Apps Created by Google Apps Script without Redeploying](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/12/07/workaround-reflecting-latest-script-to-deployed-web-apps-created-by-google-apps-script-without-redeploying/)