# How to create a doPost(e) to receive data from an external service?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a Script that receives data from a POST that I make from Postman, but every time I get the error code 301. I followed different tutorials ([Google Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and [Stack Overflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591488/doposte-does-not-return-parameters-but-dogete-does)) with not good results. 
I only need to receive the data from this POST call and send them to a SpreadSheet for their storage.

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you published your web app as public ?

Comment: Yes, it is public. I do not know if I need to configure something else :/

Comment: Can you post the link here ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're following [redirects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects). In Postman, go to your preferences, and make sure you've enabled "Automatically follow redirects".

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/), which has the redirects option very clearly visible.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I did what you said but I still get the same error. This is the Script URL https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzuXLBu9Rsq9R51xboIlTkTEqUTKyfJisRboeYkPKAUmp_OUw/exec

Comment: That image isn't viewable

Comment: Sorry, here you can see the result I get https://drive.google.com/open?id=1erQmFTkedAuOsAaL8kvrdDZtsvHtm4de

Comment: That's not the same error. It's a 401 unauthorized error. I just visited the link and your app is not public.

Comment: Yes, Sorry my bad. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This link you have commented in one answer : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzuXLBu9Rsq9R51xboIlTkTEqUTKyfJisRboeYkPKAUmp_OUw/exec

When I tried opening, it's asking me to Give permissions.

Which means MAYBE you're not "Executing the app as" yourself [me(your email)]. Rather you have selected something else like "User who is accessing"

So if you want to access it via Postman then you need to implement proper authentication or Execute it on your behalf.

Hope this helps you.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works now perfectly. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Great to know it helped you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers